# Installing Asterisk inside a CentOS docker image on Xubuntu

Tags: asterisk, docker

I'm trying to install an Asterisk server inside a CentOS 6.5 docker image running on Xubuntu 14.04.
I downloaded Dahdi from `wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/dahdi-linux-complete/releases/dahdi-linux-complete-2.4.1.2+2.4.1.tar.gz`, but when I start to install it using make all, I get the following error:

```
bash-4.1# make all
make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.4.1.2+2.4.1/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.4.1.2+2.4.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
Attempting to download dahdi-fwload-vpmadt032-1.25.0.tar.gz
--2014-07-26 07:06:14--  http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/firmware/releases/dahdi-fwload-vpmadt032-1.25.0.tar.gz
Resolving downloads.digium.com... 76.164.171.238, 2001:470:e0d4::ee
Connecting to downloads.digium.com|76.164.171.238|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 149360 (146K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `dahdi-fwload-vpmadt032-1.25.0.tar.gz'

100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 149,360     88.4K/s   in 1.6s    

2014-07-26 07:06:17 (88.4 KB/s) - `dahdi-fwload-vpmadt032-1.25.0.tar.gz' saved [149360/149360]

make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.4.1.2+2.4.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.13.0-30-generic kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.4.1.2+2.4.1/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't understand why I'm getting error that I don't have headers for kernel 3.13.0-30 because when I run

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

On Xubuntu, I get:

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic is already the newest version.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install DAHDI? You almost certainly do not need it.

Comment: Why you just not installing it on Xubuntu?

Comment: DAHDI (Digium/Asterisk Hardware Device Interface) is the open source device interface technology used to control Digium and other legacy telephony interface cards. Docker containers aren't really for device drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile it outside the container, and just do the make install part of the process inside. Or just set the right repository and install a package with the needed version of it.

Just 2 warnings, if anything requires I.e.  loading kernel modules probably will require extra privileges to run inside a container (maybe the compiling process tried to check things of the kernel that you can't access from a simple container) and using SIP (a common requirement for asterisk) will require to enable more than a few ports when running it